# IAP_CLIENT_ID on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I try to perform a programmatic authentication for authenticating from a desktop app ([Link to the tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_desktop_app)).

I got stuck at the point where the IAP_CLIENT_ID is needed.

> Use the code below where REFRESH_TOKEN is the token from the sign-in
> flow, IAP_CLIENT_ID is the primary client ID used to access your
> application, and DESKTOP_CLIENT_ID and DESKTOP_CLIENT_SECRET are the
> client

How can I generate this IAP_CLIENT_ID? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to the console:

- API & Services -> Credentials
- Here you have a table `OAuth2 Client ID`
- Find the line with the name `IAP-App-Engine-app`
- Copy the Client ID on the right of the line

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the Client ID using the gcloud cli, like this:

```bash
$ gcloud compute backend-services describe my-backend-pool 
--project=my-project-name --global --format="value[](iap.oauth2ClientId)"
```

Answer (score -1):

There's an unofficial way of getting the Client ID (`IAP_CLIENT_ID`) using the following code:

```py
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

client_id = None
requires_iap = False

url = "https://myservice.company.com/"

response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)

if response.status_code == 302:
    location = response.headers.get('location')
    query = parse_qs(urlparse(location).query) or {}
    if 'client_id' in query:
        client_id = query['client_id'][0]
        requires_iap = True

if requires_iap:
    print(f"Server requires IAP, IAP_CLIENT_ID={client_id}")
else:
    print("Server does not require IAP")
```

As this relies on an internal redirect, which may change in the future, please do not rely on this blindly.